# Can Beam/Dataflow keep state after you stop a pipeline and start a new one?

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I am trying to understand how dataflow/Beam manages state. When using kafka streams for example, it is possible to stop and restart your application and continue with the last state.

Does Beam/Dataflow have similar possibilities?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While you cannot snapshot Dataflow's state today, you can snapshot the Pub/Sub subscription where Dataflow gets its data from and restart later on. Review Cloud Pub/Sub [Seek](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/replay-overview) and Replay feature. More on the integration can be found [here](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/using-cloud-pubsub-seek).